# Modesim VHDL testbench

Tags: testing, vhdl, modelsim

I have a problem: I've tried to simulate my project by the testbench, but ModelSim wrote this message:

> Error: C:/.../testbench.vhd(62): (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "arst".

And the same message for each other ports of testbench's component.

Also, next one type of messages, for internal signals of testbench:

> Error: C:/.../testbench.vhd(63): (vcom-1484) Unknown formal identifier ARST_STIM

Top-entity `top_test` and each other entities in one common folder with testbench, so I do not understand what is a reason of the problem. I've posted the code of my testbench below:

```
-- Created:
--          by - Desmond.UNKNOWN (DESMOND-PC)
--          at - 00:52:37 07.03.2016
--

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;


ENTITY testbench IS
END testbench;

ARCHITECTURE rtl OF testbench IS

   -- Architecture declarations

   -- Internal signal declarations


   -- Component declarations
   COMPONENT top_test
      PORT (
         arst             : IN     std_logic;
         bithigh          : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         bitlow           : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         ca_bh10          : OUT    std_logic;
         ch_ca_data       : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         ch_s             : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         clk120MHz        : IN     std_logic;
         clk240Mhz        : IN     std_logic;
         clock_value_high : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         clock_value_low  : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         dac_1            : OUT    std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         dac_2            : OUT    std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         freq_setup       : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         led              : OUT    std_logic;
         level            : IN     std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
         out_symb         : OUT    std_logic;
         pps              : IN     std_logic
      );
   END COMPONENT;

--------------------------------------
signal LED,CA_OUT,MOD_OUT : std_logic;
signal ARST_STIM,CLK_120MHZ,CLK_240MHZ,PPS_STIM : std_logic := '0';
signal BIT_HIGH_STIM,BIT_LOW_STIM,LEVEL_STIM,CA_DATA_STIM,FREQ_STIM,CLK_LOW_STIM,CLK_HIGH_STIM,CH_SELECT_STIM : std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal DAC_1, DAC_2 : std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
--------------------------------------
constant CLK_120MHZ_PERIOD : TIME := 8.33 ns;
constant CLK_240MHZ_PERIOD : TIME := 4.15 ns;
-------------------------------------


BEGIN

 U_0 : top_test
 PORT MAP (
ARST_STIM => arst,
CLK_120MHZ => clk120MHz ,
CLK_240MHZ => clk240Mhz,
PPS_STIM => pps,
BIT_HIGH_STIM => bithigh ,
BIT_LOW_STIM => bitlow,
LEVEL_STIM => level, 
CA_DATA_STIM => ch_ca_data,
FREQ_STIM => freq_setup,
CLK_LOW_STIM => clock_value_low,
CLK_HIGH_STIM => clock_value_high,
CH_SELECT_STIM => ch_s,
DAC_1 => dac_1,
DAC_2 => dac_2,
CA_OUT =>  ca_bh10,
LED => led,
MOD_OUT => out_symb
);

--------------------------
CLK_GENERATION : process
begin
CLK_120MHZ <= not CLK_120MHZ after (CLK_120MHZ_PERIOD/2);
CLK_240MHZ <= not CLK_240MHZ after (CLK_240MHZ_PERIOD/2);
end process CLK_GENERATION;
----------------------------

STIM_PROC : process
begin
ARST_STIM <= '1';
PPS_STIM <= '0';
wait for 100 ns;
CH_SELECT_STIM <= (others=>'0');
CLK_LOW_STIM <= "00010111010110001110001000011001";
CLK_HIGH_STIM <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
FREQ_STIM <= "00000010001000100010001000100010";
LEVEL_STIM <= "00000000000000000000000000110010";
CA_DATA_STIM <= "00000000000000000000000000000110";
BIT_LOW_STIM <= "00100110100101111011000000000000";
BIT_HIGH_STIM <= "10101010010010111110100001010101";
wait for 1800 ns;
PPS_STIM <= '1';
wait for 100 ns;
PPS_STIM <= '0';
wait for 1000 ns;
CH_SELECT_STIM <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
wait for 999999000 ns;
PPS_STIM <= '1';
wait for 100 ns;
PPS_STIM <= '0';
wait for 10000000 ns;
end process STIM_PROC;


END rtl;
```

Comment: The port map is not correct. You need to switch the sides. `arst => ARST_STIM,`. `x => y` indicates no data flow. It says: map the port `x` of my component to a local signal `y`.

Comment: Well, is it true algorith : signal_of_component => signal_of_testbench?

Comment: Don't confuse `<=` (signal assignment) with `=>` (mapping). Because you swapped the sides, your tool is seeking for a signal called `arst` which was not declared, which in turn causes a missing identifier error.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008, 6.5.& Association lists, association_element ::= [ formal_part => ] actual_part. formal part in this case is the name of a port signal from the instantiated component. The actual part is the name of the signal you connect to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Paebbels